# fixed footer on bottom of the page with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with a footer. I tried to make a footer stick to the bottom of my page

but when i scroll the footer scrolls to the top also. like it is fixed on the page. On my website i use jQuery, jQuery Mobile, bootstrap.

there is also an extra footerbar that does stay fixed but i can not write anything in it.

```
<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
<p>footer</p>
</div>
```

example on [m.alfanet.be](http://m.alfanet.be)

Comment: `data-role=page` should be the parent of `data-role=footer`, `header`, `content`, `panel` and `popup`.

Answer (score 1):

Your page layout is not correct, you are missing a div with `data-role='page'`

### Basic page jquery mobile layout:

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
       <a href="#doSomething">doSomething</a>
    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
        <a href="#mypanel">Open panel</a>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

    <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
        <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tronc/Sh6BF/

Comment: you can add `panel` and `popup`, for future reference :) add this img http://i44.tinypic.com/2dvj4hz.png

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. this basicly works but not when i wont the footer fixed on the bottem of the screen, so that the content scrolls under it.

Comment: this is the page layout according to the jqm you have to work with. fixing the footer to the bottom of the page is another problem, which is already well discussed on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are designing a site for mobile phones (as you are making use of jQuery Mobile).

Fixed positions on mobile phones don't work pretty well. The behavior of your fixed element will be different for each mobile browser.

Take a look at [this great study by Brad Frost](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/).

Comment: Please note the date of the article - November 10, 2011. As for web dev, that's a highly outdated source of information.

Comment: Just take a tablet and test it by yourself. New Apple devices deal with it pretty well, but try Nexus tablet or other OS and you will see the annoying results. Also, consider not everybody is in the last version of the operative system (and specially with Android users)

Comment: DiH is correct. This source is now outdated and no longer relevant.